# Can I pass form data/variables to php in jQuery script using AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, form-data

I have a form which passes data to a jQuery script on the same page.  The form looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<input type="radio" name="favourites" value="all" checked="checked"> all tracks &nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name ="favourites" value="favourites"> favourites only<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="filter" class="submit" value="filter"><br>
</form>
```

The value for favourites is then retrieved by PHP within a jQuery script in the head of the same page, which dynamically generates a MySQL query.  But this happens because the page is reloaded.  If possible I would like to pass the form data/variables to the jQuery script without reloading the page, using AJAX.  I'm aware that I can manipulate html and css using AJAX, but can I also manipulate the jQuery script in the head?  If so, how would I go about this?

Comment: You don't need to manipulate the script in the head, you need to write a new one that sends the form with ajax instead.

Comment: @adeneo Do you mean that I need to reproduce the entire script from the head, adding the ajax for processing the form?  Sorry I'm relatively new to AJAX!

Answer (score 3):

For simplicity reasons, give the form a unique ID, then simply make a jquery post to an AJAX file designed for this purpose.

Example:

**HTML**

```
<form id="postForm" method="POST">
    <input type="radio" name="filter" value="1" /> Only favorites
    <input type="radio" name="filter" value="2" /> Everything
    <input type="submit" name="postFormSubmit" />
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('form#postForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //Prevents a page reload
    var filter = $(this).find("input[@name=filter]:checked").val(); //Gets the value of "filter"
    $.post("/path/to/ajax.php",{filterType:filter},function(){
        // Callback, could make the data output attach to this.
    });
});
```

That's where I would start atleast :)

Comment: @Raminson - just noticed the formatting was all messed up. Thanks for cleaning! :)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/). Code would go something like this.

HTML:

```
<form id="postForm" method="POST">
    <input type="radio" name="filter" value="1" /> Only favorites
    <input type="radio" name="filter" value="2" /> Everything
    <input type="submit" name="postFormSubmit" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery("#postForm").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery.post("/ajax.php", jQuery("#postForm").serialize(), function(){
    //done
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I will take a look at the article you linked to.  Being rather new to ajax I am a little confused though.  What goes in ajax.php?  Is this the main index.php page that all my code is in at the moment?

Comment: You want to split your .php files from the rest of the site. Having all the code that the site depends on in a single file causes alot of issues down the road. Anyway: In the ajax.php, that's where you'll put your SQL-query (or object instance, if you're using OOPHP).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to write it on your own you may be interested in this plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/form/